# Constructor arguments in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a question which might be a very simple one but I can't find the way out.

Here are the `Parent` and `Child` classes which will work without a problem.

```
public class Parent {

    private A a;
    private B b;

    Parent (A a, B b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public class A {}

    public class B {}

    private class C {}

    public class Child extends Parent {
        private final C c;

        Child(A a, B b, C c,) {
            super(a, b);
            this.c = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the problem: Fields `b` and `c` are fields of some other class `ClassBC` and `ClassBC` is one of the argument of class `Child`. i.e.,

```
 public class Child extends Parent {
    private D d;
    Child(A a, C c) {
        // I must call super(...) here; but can't do that without `b`
        ClassBC classBC = new ClassBC(c);
        B b = classBC.getB();
        D d = classBC.getD();
    }
    // some methods
}

private class ClassBC{
    private D d;

    ClassBC(C c){
         // do something here to get 'B' and 'D'
    }
    public D getd(){
        return d;
    }

    public B getB(){
        return b;
    }
}
```

So:

- Am I being stupid or breaking some rules here?
- I tried to use Builder in `Parent` class such that it can be used in the constructor of `Child` class. As expected, it compiled but failed because fields of `Parent` classes are not available in `Child` class.
- I want to avoid using builder in `Child` class because it will lead to too may changes in the repository. What else I can try?
- This is a minimal example, actual classes are complex with couple of more arguments.

Comment: `super(a, new ClassBC(c).getB())`?

Comment: Where is `b` in `ClassBC` coming from?

Comment: @JoeC I can't do that, let me edit my question to clarify it.

Comment: Can you add an additional constructor: `Parent (A a)`?

Comment: Technically, I can do that but without 'B' couple of functions will not work. Would you recommend to use `Parent (A a)` and then in the constructor of `Child`, I do something like: `setB(b)`. Probably, not a good idea, since, I will expose others to make mistakes.

Comment: Depends on how you get an instance of `B`. It would be clearest if that dependency would also be injected into the `Child` constructor `Child(A a, B b, C c)`.

Answer (score 3):

Cant you do it with factory method. Make Child constructor private, and add static method `createChild` create child objects from this factory method.
Create your `ClassBC` objects before calling Child constructor.

Comment: yes, that's a way but that would lead to changes in 500+ more places.

Comment: @novice Ok, can you add a default constructor to parent. And call that when you create Child. after super() line passes. You can use setters to set the required objects to parent. Is that ok for your case, I don't if your objects are immutable or not.

Comment: yes, I thought that too (Mick Mnemonic also suggested in a similar direction; comment's of question). However, is this a good practice (just asking)?

Comment: I think first thing to achieve should be making something that works, good practices comes later. Maybe I think wrong :). And it is a good solution for this problem. I would chose factory method though

Answer (score 2):

I think that should work for you

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    private D d;

    private ClassBC bc;

    Child(A a, C c) {
        // Inline
        this(a, new ClassBC(c));
    }

    Child(A a, ClassBC bc) {
        super(a, bc.getB());
        this.bc = bc;
        this.d = bc.getD();
    }
}
```